# How to close ActionMode when it's replace by other fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I've problem when using `ListView` in `Fragment`. When i using `MultiChoiceModelListener`, it will display `ActionMode` when i Long click on the item in `ListView`.

The problem is :

1. When `ActionMode` is activated, and user replace that fragment with other fragment the actionmode still there, take a look the picture below.
2. When I use `ActionMode mode = null` and instantiate that `mode` variable `onCreateActionMode` plus implement it in `onDestroyActionMode` and `onDestroyView`, please take a look the snippet code. The **Problem number one is solved**, but it's **open another problem**, because `mode.finish()` is called in `onDestroyView` when fragment orientation change my checked item in `ListView` disappear.
3. When I delete `onDestroyView()` method, **I solved the problem number two**, **but** Problem **number one is open again**.

[image]

This is my snippet code :

```
//My ActionModeListener
private class MyActionMode implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {
            String nfile = ((DataFileProvider) adapter.getItem(i)).getNfile();
            if (b) {
                selections.add(nfile);
            } else {
                selections.remove(nfile);
            }
            actionMode.setTitle(selections.size() + " " + getString(R.string.item_selected));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            mode = actionMode;
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_file_action_mode, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            actionMode.setTitle(selections.size() + " " + getString(R.string.item_selected));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            selections.clear();
            mode = null;
            showMessage("ListDocFileFragment : onDestroyActionMode");
        }
    }
```

This is my snippet code when handle fragment livecycle

```
//My OnResume,OnPause,and OnDestroyView in Fragment
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            default_location = getArguments().getString("default_location");
        }
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("ActionMode")) {
            selections = getActivity().getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ActionMode");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(selections.isEmpty() && list_doc_file.getCheckedItemCount() > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                list_doc_file.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
            selections.clear();
        }
        showMessage("ListDocFileFragment : onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (selections != null) {
            getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("ActionMode", selections);
        }
        showMessage("ListDocFileFragment : onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if(mode != null){
            mode.finish();
        }

        showMessage("ListDocFileFragment : onDestroyView");
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

My Question is how **to solved three problem above**, **without** open another problem like i did ?

I've searching for another solution in this stack, but i got nothing. When i implement their solution it's always open another problem. Any suggestion ?

Comment: <activity android:name="Activityname"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity> try this one ???

Comment: I've tried it before.it's solved problem two, but open problem one again. :D